# Lazy load SSH keys from remote server using SSH agent and AddKeysToAgent

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I have my ssh-agent configured with `AddKeysToAgent yes` to lazy load keys into the agent only when they are first used. I also configured `ForwardAgent yes` in my ssh config for a remote server.

I want to ssh into the remote server, then clone private repositories from GitHub using ssh. On the remote server, I am executing `ssh -T git@github.com` to confirm that the ssh agent forwarding works correctly. I have different keys for the remote server and GitHub.

Here are my observations:

- On my local machine, if I execute `ssh -T git@github.com`, it causes the key used with GitHub to be loaded into the ssh agent. Subsequently, when I log into the remote server, the agent is forwarded and executing `ssh -T git@github.com` on the remote server works.
- If I do not have any keys loaded into my ssh agent, when I ssh into the remote server, the key for the remote server is loaded into the ssh agent. From the remote server, if I attempt to ssh into GitHub using `ssh -T git@github.com`, it does not work and returns `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)`.

Is there any way to lazy load the GitHub key into the ssh agent from a remote server that is using the ssh agent in forwarded mode?

Comment: Think on what's doing the loading. `ssh` on the remote system has no idea about where the keys for GitHub might be - sure you have a forwarded agent's socket file, but as far as that `ssh` is concerned, the socket file could be for a local agent, it could be a remote service forwarded in some way other than ssh, etc. The agent itself also doesn't have any idea - it can load some keys by default, but otherwise it's just loading what it's told to.